# ¿Cómo accedo a un onkeyup de un elemento de un array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<input class="search_query form-control" type="text" name="key" id="key" placeholder="Buscar..." >
<div id="suggestions" name="suggestions"></div>

$('#key').on('keyup', function() {}
```

Y funciona correctamente, pero yo necesito poder crear varias líneas (eso ya se como se hace), y poder acceder a onkeyup de cada línea pero no se como hacerlo.

Os pongo un ejemplo:

```
 <input class="search_query form-control" type="text" name="key[]" id="key[]" placeholder="Buscar..." >
    <div id="suggestions[]" name="suggestions[]"></div>

  <input class="search_query form-control" type="text" name="key[]" id="key[]" placeholder="Buscar..." >
    <div id="suggestions[]" name="suggestions[]"></div>

$('#key').on('keyup', function() {}
```

En este caso el onkeyup no funciona. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?.

Gracias.

Comment: Cada elemento del DOM debe tener un único identificador `id` distinto de todos los demás elementos del mismo documento. Tal como lo planteas en tu pregunta, tienes elementos con `id` repetido. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si cambio a:

```
<input class="search_query form-control" type="text" name="key[]" id="key1" placeholder="Buscar..." >
<div id="suggestions1" name="suggestions[]"></div>

<input class="search_query form-control" type="text" name="key[]" id="key2" placeholder="Buscar..." >
<div id="suggestions2" name="suggestions[]"></div>
```

Yo no se cuantas lineas se van a crear, no tiene limite, tengo que crear diferentes

```
$('#key1').on('keyup', function() {}
$('#key2').on('keyup', function() {}
```

Probando esto, no es lo logico, cuando hago onkeyup en el key2 no lo reconoce.

Answer (score 0):

Si la función que quieres ejecutar en el keyup es la misma para todas, puedes asociar el evento a una clase en lugar de un id.

```
$('.search-query').on('keyup', function() {}
```

Así cualquier input con la 'class' search-query, tendrá el evento keyup asociado.

```js
$('.search_query').keyup(function(){
  var element = $(this);
  console.log(element.val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="search_query" id="1"/>
<input class="search_query" id="2"/>
<input class="search_query" id="3"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Lo he probado y sobre la primera linea funciona pero cuando creo la segunda linea no reconoce  la funcion,                                                                                       $('.search-query').on('keyup', function() {}                                                                  Alguna idea porque no lo hace?

Comment: Puedes poner el contenido de la función?

Comment: He añadido la funcion como respuesta

Comment: No veo que puede fallar, échale un ojo a mi respuesta, he añadido un ejemplo, prueba a poner console.log('funciona') en varios puntos de tu js e itenta averiguar si es que ni siquiera se llama a la función, o es algo dentro de la función que está causando problemas.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addRow() {
     var addRow = '<tr>\n' +
                '         <td><input class="search_query form-control" type="text" name="key[]" id="key[]" placeholder="Buscar..." ><div id="suggestions" name="suggestions"></div></td>\n'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="desc[]" class="form-control desc" id="desc[]" value=""></td>\n'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="form-control qty" id="qty[]" value="1"></td>\n'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control price" id="price[]" value=""></td>\n'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="dis[]" class="form-control dis" id="dis[]" value=""></td>\n'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="dis2[]" class="form-control dis2" id="dis2[]" value=""></td>\n'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="tax[]" class="form-control tax" id="tax[]" value=""></td>\n'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount" id="amount[]" value=""></td>\n'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="base[]" class="form-control base" id="base[]" value="">\n'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="tdto[]" class="form-control tdto" id="tdto[]" value="">\n'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="ttax[]" class="form-control ttax" id="ttax[]" value="">\n'+
            '<td><input type="checkbox" name="record" id="delete-row"></td>\n'+
            '</tr>';
                 $('tbody').append(addRow);
        };
```

Comment: Las respuestas que estas poniendo no son respuestas reales. Deberías de editar tu pregunta y añadirlo ahi.

Comment: No sabia como hacerlo y lo hice como respuesta. Ahora ya lo se. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas elementos dinámicos no puedes seleccionarlos directamente con JQuery.

Prueba a utilizar este selector:

```
$(document).on('keyup','.search_query', function() {
    //código del keyup...
})
```

Comment: Gracias, si que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

La funcion no la llama porque pongo un console.log y un alert y no dice nada, pero si miro el código generado yo lo veo bien.

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div id="sproduct"> 
            <input class="search_query form-control" type="text" name="key[]" id="key_1" placeholder="Buscar..." data-type="reference">
            <div id="suggestions" name="suggestions"></div>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td><input class="search_query form-control desc" type="text" name="desc[]" id="desc_1" value="" data-type="description"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="form-control qty" id="qty[]" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control price" id="price[]" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="dis[]" class="form-control dis" id="dis[]" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="dis2[]" class="form-control dis2" id="dis2[]" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tax[]" class="form-control tax" id="tax[]" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount" id="amount[]" value=""></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="base[]" class="form-control base" id="base[]" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="tdto[]" class="form-control tdto" id="tdto[]" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="ttax[]" class="form-control ttax" id="ttax[]" value="">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="record" id="delete-row"></td>
         </tr>
    <tr>
         <td><input class="search_query form-control" type="text" name="key[]" id="key2" placeholder="Buscar..."><div id="suggestions" name="suggestions"></div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="desc[]" class="form-control desc" id="desc2" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="form-control qty" id="qty[]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control price" id="price[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dis[]" class="form-control dis" id="dis[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dis2[]" class="form-control dis2" id="dis2[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tax[]" class="form-control tax" id="tax[]" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" class="form-control amount" id="amount[]" value=""></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="base[]" class="form-control base" id="base[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="tdto[]" class="form-control tdto" id="tdto[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ttax[]" class="form-control ttax" id="ttax[]" value="">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="record" id="delete-row"></td>
        </tr></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya he econtrado la solución a que no funciona la función keyup en las lineas generadas automáticamente.

Lo que hay que hacer es un bind que ahora es obsoleto y hay que usara la funcion on y de esta forma ya funciona.

```
$(".table-bordered").on("keyup", ".search_query", function(){
                        var element = $(this);
                        console.log(element.val());
          });
```

Gracias por su ayuda.